# Simply setting a Class A value from Class B in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, setter, synthesize

In Objective-C, I want to set a `synthesized (assigned)` attribute in Class `Compass` from Class `B`

This is my code...

```
for(Compass * ind in CompassList){  
    if([[(Compass*)ind showAnalog] isEqualToString:str]){  
        ind.analogValue=11.0;  
    }  
}
```

However, I am getting this error...

```
Request for member analogValue in something not a structure or union.
```

I managed to avoid this error by using my own setter and calling it like `[ind updateValue:11.0];`. However, when I call the synthesized getter later like `[(Compass*)currentDevice analogValue];` in another class, I get the following exception...

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException': [Compass digitalValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613ca20
```

Could someone please help me to understand how I should be doing this.

Comment: 1. Please show us the declaration for Compass. 2. In Class B's interface file, are you importing the header where that declaration occurs?

Comment: Yes, I am importing the Compass.h in Class B

Answer (score 0):

You are fast enumerating indicatorList as type `Indicator` then one line below you are casting it as `Compass`. If this is not a typo and all of the values are of type `Compass` then change the code to read

```
for(Compass * compass in indicatorList){  
    if([[compass showAnalog] isEqualToString:str]){  
        compass.analogValue=11.0;  
    }  
}
```

Now for you actual problem you have posted no code that relates to the issue. I am guessing the cause is from some code that `showAnalog` is invoking which in turns calls `[(Compass*)currentDevice analogValue];`. This may all be related to incorrect casting or not fully implementing the `Compass` class.

Comment: hmm, there is no problem with the if statement. I tested everything. Im really excited where the problem is

Comment: I am just not sure why you are enumerating one type then casting it to another type directly below. There is no issue with it just seems like unnecessary casting. You may want to still post additional source code as Chuck requested in the comments above.